# jquery append mutiple lines to html from an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is what i have right now

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET"
    , url:'{{url("/api/getcart")}}'
    , dataType:"json",
     success: function(data){

         $('#price').append(data.cartitems[1].product.price);
         $('#qty').append(data.cartitems[1].qty);
         $('#name').append('<a href=/product/'+data.cartitems[1].product.slug+'>'+data.cartitems[1].product.name+'<a>');


         $('#subtotal').append(data.subtotal);
        console.log(data)

    }
   , error: function(e) {
       console.log(e)
       }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h2>Cart</h2>
  <ul id="items" class="cd-cart-items">
    <li>
      <span id="qty" class="cd-price"></span>
      <span  class="cd-price">-</span> 
      <span id="name" class="cd-name"></span>
      <div id="price" class="cd-price">$</div>
         <a href="#" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace"><img
         src="img/delete.svg"
         alt="remove product from cart" height="10px" width="10px" />
         </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

and it works fine but i need to make this dynamic, i mean if i had 2 items i cart this will still show only one
my js skills are far from good , 
the question here is :

**how to make this append a new**  `<li>` **for each object**

Comment: Use [forEach](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp) or [.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). Put the function around the lines that append the data to the webpage, just inside the success handler. Hope this helps.

Comment: that would add them to the same element, i need to create one then add to the new one

Comment: Try not to create duplicate id's in elements created from a  loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so what you're asking is that you want the script to create a `li` element for each object. Please excuse my knowledge of JSON. I'll be the first to say that it's minimal.
I would go with a [for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) for this one. For this example, set the initial variable to `i` like so:

```
for (i=0; i <= *number of JSON objects*; i++) {
    //code here
}
```

With this piece of code, anything inside the brackets will be run once for each object. Now all you need to do is put this next bit of JavaScript in between the curly braces:

```
var price = '<div id="price" class="cd-price">$' + data.cartitems[i].product.price + '</div>';

var qty = '<span id="qty" class="cd-price">' + data.cartitems[i].qty + '</span>';

var name = '<a href="/product/' + data.cartitems[i].product.slug + '">' + data.cartitems[i].product.name + '</a>';

var html = '<li>' + qty + '<span  class="cd-price">-</span>' + name + price + '<a href="#" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace"><img src="img/delete" alt="remove product from cart" height="10px" width="10px" /></a></li>

$('#items').append(html);
```

This bit gathers the values of the objects and stores them in variables, to be used in the final `append` statement. You will notice that i have used `i` for the index in the `data.cartitems[]` sections. This will substitute `i` for what ever number the `for loop` is up to, and will then cycle through all of the objects. For example, if the `for loop` is up to it's second run through, `i` will equal `1`. Why `1` and not `2`, you ask? It's because indexing starts at `0`.

The finished result is:

```
for (i=0; i <= *number of JSON objects*; i++) {
    var price = '<div id="price" class="cd-price">$' + data.cartitems[i].product.price + '</div>';

    var qty = '<span id="qty" class="cd-price">' + data.cartitems[i].qty + '</span>';

    var name = '<a href="/product/' + data.cartitems[i].product.slug + '">' + data.cartitems[i].product.name + '</a>';

    var html = '<li>' + qty + '<span  class="cd-price">-</span>' + name + price + '<a href="#" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace"><img src="img/delete" alt="remove product from cart" height="10px" width="10px" /></a></li>

    $('#items').append(html);
}
```

The HTML part only needs to be:

```
<h2>Cart</h2>
<ul id="items" class="cd-cart-items"></ul>
```

Hopefully this helps, and makes sense.

Comment: Works fine thanks , my js skills are very bad :s its realy nice to have help from a fellow Self taught  Student :3

Comment: You might already know of it, but https://www.codecademy.com is great for free tutorials on various languages. Check it out.

Comment: [The New Boston](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php) is another source for free tutorials, and Alex Garret (owner of codeacademy.com) did hundreds of their videos. I learned the majority of my self-taught skills from these two (free) resources.

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

### Cart

```
  <ul id="items" class="cd-cart-items">

</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type:"GET"
    , url:'{{url("/api/getcart")}}'
    , dataType:"json",
     success: function(data){

       $.each(data.cartitems,function() {

$('#items').append('<li><span class="qty cd-price">'+$(this).qty+'</span><span  class="cd-price">-</span><span id="name" class="name cd-name"><a href="/product/'+$(this).product.slug+'">'+$(this).product.name+'<a></span><div class="price cd-price">$'+$(this).product.price+'</div><a href="#" class="cd-item-remove cd-img-replace"><img src="img/delete.svg" alt="remove product from cart" height="10px" width="10px" /></a></li>');
});         
         $('#subtotal').append(data.subtotal);
        console.log(data);

    }
   , error: function(e) {
       console.log(e)
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: can you type the output of `console.log($(this).slug,$(this).product.slug,$(this).product)` ?

Comment: same error but in the console.log line , anyway this is solved man , thank you